# Reverse proxy with google apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, dns, google-apps

I'm using a google app engine application on my domain with google apps.
Because of China blocking google apps, I'd like to hide google apps by putting a layer between my domain and google apps. 
Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/c83a316d28eb8ea7?pli=1) and [here](http://www.haohaoreport.com/General/Google-App-Engine-blocked-in-China-and-solution) are links that might help you. Some users have overcome the problem using reverse proxy. I really pity for the Chinese people who are deprieved of google access.

Answer (score 0):

I for one I am getting a cheap PHP hosting somewhere else and will just redirect requests using php_curl. That's from iPhone apps though so I can chose which server to point to depending on the origin.